# Why shouldn't we show the action bar without status bar in an Android app?

Tags: android

From [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status), I came to know that we should never show the action bar without the status bar in Android apps.
[image]

What is the reason for this? Is it something related to user experience or is it some feature which is going to get deprecated in the future?